# Prevent page from flickering when using javascript and anchor links

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

1. I'm using scrollreveal on my website, and it mostly works well, but
   sometimes the page is flickering just before the divs reveals and
   make it looks like the page is loading, before the code is executed
   after loaded http://regen.no/samarbeidspartnere when reloading
   the page, you clearly see the problem.
2. Sometimes when using the #anchor link to a div with the id, the page is also flickering.http://regen.no/start changing between
   "**forsiden**" and "**påmelding**" the page are flickering before it
   jumps to the target div.

Is there any way to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a code example?

Comment: when using the scroll reveal im following the documentation from https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollreveal. Anchor links are just simple <a> link with target "#id".

Comment: You'd get more help if you can paste sample code to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1):

By using the `performance` tab in Chrome developer tools, I did a recording (changing between two anchor points) and I notice that when a link is hit, the page goes directly there and then the smooth scrolling effect takes place. To describe this with a small example let's say that the user is at `#bottom` and clicks to go to `#top`:

- The page goes directly to `#top`
- The smooth scrolling effect takes place, so the page goes back to `#bottom`
- Smooth scrolling back to `#top`

This is why you get this flickering and flashing result.

Maybe you should use a `event.preventDefault();` somewhere in your js code.